# Parse multiline event in logstash

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, parsing, logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to parse the below event in logstash grok filter but it's failing.

event sample :

2023-05-11 00:20:26,103 [http-apr-7777-exec-46] INFO com.welcome.ws.AccountWebServiceImpl. - Request given by the user

<ns2:GetCustomerBalanceReq xmlns="url" xmlns:ns2="url">

testt
**
xls

ns2:ID/EID/5000000004/123456****1234</ns2:ID>
</ns2:GetCustomerBalanceReq>

2023-05-11 00:20:26,144 [http-apr-7777-exec-46] INFO com.welcome.svc.AccountService

and I am using the below Grok pattern:

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} \[%{DATA:thread}\] %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} %{DATA:web} - Request given by the user \r\n
```

it says the Grok pattern doesn't match anything

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following websites to test your grok parser.

1. https://grokdebugger.com/
2. https://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match?example=2

For multiline you need to combine lines into one line during ingestion. [Logstash multiline codec plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/8.6/plugins-codecs-multiline.html) or filebeat multiline codec plugin can help you to solve it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I was trying using Grok debugger in elasticsearch but I wasn't able to handle the multiline event, knowing that the sample I provided is one event which needs to be parsed.